# Codeigniter Active record: greater than statement

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I'm trying to convert a "greater than" where statement to CI's Active Record syntax. When I use this snippet

```
    $this->db->join('product_stocks', "product_stocks.size_id_fk = product_attributes.id", "left");
    $this->db->where('product_stocks.stock_level', '> 1');      
    $result = $this->db->get('product_attributes')->result_array();
```

Then print $this->db->last_query(); shows `WHERE`product_stocks`.`stock_level`= '> 1'` which is of course not correct. Can this be done?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$this->db->where('product_stocks.stock_level >', '1');  //moved the >
```

Answer (score 7):

Either

```
$this->db->where('product_stocks.stock_level >', '1');
```

or

```
$this->db->where(array('product_stocks.stock_level >'=>'1'));
```

should do it. Note the space between the field name and the operator; otherwise you will end up getting Error 1064.

Answer (score 4):

You Can also Pass a String parameter to where() function like this,

```
$this->db->where('product_stocks.stock_level > 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have in CI the following:

```
 $sQuery = "SELECT auftrag, saal, DATE_FORMAT(konzertdatum,'%e, %M, %Y') AS konzertdatum2 FROM auftrag 
    JOIN saal on auftrag.saal_id = saal.id 
    WHERE konzertdatum < NOW() + INTERVAL 240 DAY AND auftrag like '%$sWord%' order by konzertdatum asc LIMIT 4";
 $aOrder = $this->db->query($sQuery);
 $aOrder = $aOrder->result();
```

It works fine without CI, but when I use

```
      $this->db->select("auftrag, saal, DATE_FORMAT(konzertdatum,'%e, %M, %Y') AS konzertdatum2", false );
    $this->db->from('auftrag');
    $this->db->join('saal', 'auftrag.saal_id = saal.id');
    $this->db->like('auftrag', $sWord);
    $this->db->where('konzertdatum <', 'NOW() + Interval 240 day');

    $this->db->order_by('konzertdatum');
    $this->db->limit(4);

    $oQuery = $this->db->get();

    $aOrder = $oQuery->result();
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

it returns all results not caring about the where (although the sql seems fine):

```
SELECT auftrag, saal, DATE_FORMAT(konzertdatum, '%e, %M, %Y') AS konzertdatum2 FROM (`auftrag`) JOIN `saal` ON `auftrag`.`saal_id` = `saal`.`id` WHERE `konzertdatum` < 'NOW() + Interval 240 day' AND `auftrag` LIKE '%spangenberg%' ORDER BY `konzertdatum` LIMIT 4
```